# Adding hover tool to datashader interactive image

Tags: python, bokeh, data-analysis, datashader

I want to perform datashading on a plot created in bokeh. I encountered with [this](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/bokeh/bokeh-notebooks/blob/master/tutorial/A2%20-%20Visualizing%20Big%20Data%20with%20Datashader.ipynb) python notebook. But I want to know can I add hovertool to 
resultant image after datashading. If yes then how can I add tools like hovertool,taptool to the Interactive Image of created by datashader?

Comment: The article you mentioned sais: "When not to use datashader: For full interactivity (hover tools) with _every_ datapoint". What do you want to look at with the hover tool?